# Mysql fetch next iteration

Tags: mysql

```
 BEGIN
 DECLARE UserId INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE t_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM table;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET t_done = TRUE;
 OPEN t_cursor;
 r_loop: LOOP
  FETCH t_cursor INTO UserId;
  IF t_done THEN
    LEAVE r_loop;
  END IF;
  IF UserId < 5 THEN
     -- How to move to the next iteration, that is, to the next UserId in cursor ?
  END IF;

  UPDATE Table set val = 1 where Id = UserID;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE t_cursor;
 END;
```

Is there a command to go to the next iteration? I understand that you can get by with ELSEIF, but rewriting a lot of code, it's easier to put a condition first and if the id does not match the condition, check the next id

Comment: This is English-only website. Please post the question in English only.

Comment: [ITERATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/iterate.html). But there exists more reasonable solution - use IF with opposite condition and perform the action (UPDATE) in it. And the most reasonable solution - simply add according WHERE to the cursor code.

Comment: iterate runs the loop first ? or jumps to the next entry in the cursor. Tried Iterate, loop terminates and doesn't process all records

Comment: Well, that is, as I understand it, there is no such command, ITERATE start the loop again, and does not proceed to the next iteration.

Comment: *ITERATE start the loop again, and does not proceed to the next iteration.* ??? what is the difference between these two statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE UserId INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE t_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;                     -- variable declared
 DECLARE t_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM /* table */ test;                 -- tablename changed
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET t_done = TRUE;
 OPEN t_cursor;
 r_loop: LOOP
  FETCH t_cursor INTO UserId;
  IF t_done THEN
    LEAVE r_loop;
  END IF;
  IF UserId < 5 THEN
     -- How to move to the next iteration, that is, to the next UserId in cursor ?
     ITERATE r_loop;                                       -- ITERATE added
  END IF;

  UPDATE /* Table */ test set val = 1 where Id = UserID;   -- tablename changed
 END LOOP r_loop;                                          -- label added
 CLOSE t_cursor;
 END;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22361369a6bd47d2ef514d3ca4010fb4

Comment: Thanks, this really works. I'll go look for the reason why it doesn't work in the prodaction code)

Comment: Found the reason why I exited the loop at ITERATE r_loop;
Solution for me: 
 IF UserId < 5 THEN       
SET t_done = FALSE;
ITERATE r_loop;
END IF; 
After that, the cycle is processed completely. 5.5.68-MariaDB

Comment: @MartinRoot MySQL <> MariaDB. Always specify precise server version.

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1